# Reg PHP open source shopping cart soft ware Zend cart

Tags: cart, zen

For one of our clients we need to develop a shopping cart application. They said that they do not want Magento. So we are going to do this with Zen cart. We need to install this Zen cart and need to do customization. Also we need to create a mobile version of this.

To check on the above we downloaded Zen cart from http://sourceforge.net/projects/zencart/files/ and installed in our local machine and this is working fine.

When we try to download and check mobile version of this Zen cart we could not able to download from http://mobilezencart.com/. This ask us to do sign up. We created account for this no reply at all and not able to download.

Kindly let us know whether this mobile version is available, whether it is free  and can we download this.  If so please provide reference links or steps

Thanks

Comment: If zen cart is not a mobile friendly one kindly suggest any other mobile friendly open source shopping cart software using PHP apart from magento. Even if this is not available kindly suggest any other mobile friendly commercial shopping cart software using PHP apart from magento.

Comment: Could we use these kind of commercial templates                        http://www.12leaves.com/store/mobile-zen-cart-template.html      $40
http://www.12leaves.com/store/mobile-zen-cart-template.html      $40
http://www.pixemus.com/zen-cart-mobile-template.html               $49 - Please advice any one used these kind.

Answer (score 0):

Zen cart isn't bad as an option, I understand they want to steer away from magento since magento is way to massive for small shops.

The mobile Zen cart website is an plugin for you zen cart to make it mobile. This is what happend 5 years ago when only 2 - 5 screen sizes were available. 
These days we would use a responsive website (the one were you can scale your browser window and see the changes happening for smaller screen sizes).

Take a look at [Themeforest](http://themeforest.net/category/ecommerce/zen-cart) for some great responsive templates or on the [Download](http://www.zen-cart.com/downloads.php?do=cat&id=2) page for Zen Cart.

So as an answer to your question, you could use the mobile plugin. But since they are not responding on your mails and it looks like the website is quite outdated (looks like an iPhone 3G/3Gs) I'm doubting the plugin is still active.

This brings me neatly to another point. At the moment I'm looking into all the major platforms and I've have to say, Zen Cart looks like an old dad trying to look cool. It's based on OsCommerce and it seems like core development isn't really going fast and they keep lumping behind on both design and code. Like there is no API feature built-in... or even an WYSIWYG editor. Next to that the backend feels like 15 years old. Don't get me wrong, Zen Cart will do the job, just don't expect fancy and new features.

On the other hand, if you really would go responsive, go Presta Shop! They've released v1.6 yesterday and it features all out responsiveness (both in storefront as backend).

That said, If you are a experienced coder go with Presta Shop (or even Magento, but since the client doesn't want it, it's not in the picture) if you are more off a DIY coder Zen Cart is perfect.